# Is there any difference between "Leider habe ich ..." and "Ich habe leider..." semantically?

Tags: usage, semantics

Is there any semantic difference between these two sentences according to their formal or informal/daily usage?

> Leider habe ich keine Zeit.

> Ich habe leider keine Zeit

Comment: When I went to school, we were taught not to start sentences with „Ich“ when writing a letter, as that was seen as egocentric. I don’t know if it’s still the case today. Apart from that, I’d say the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is the same, but the first sentence puts some emphasis on *leider* because it's at the beginning of the sentence.